# Replication Lag while migrating a live database

Tags: mysql, migration, master-slave-replication

I have a live database that is on a server(mysql 5.7) that I want to completely migrate to a droplet created on an infrastructure provider with (mysql 8.1). I would also like to have a master slave setup to be on an infrastructure provider so I have created two droplets (primary and secondary) having same configuration and created a master slave connection between them. So now for migration, I have taken a remote dump of the database on to my primary server and have created a master slave connection between main database server (as master) and primary (as slave). I am keeping my database on the main hard drive and have separated the binlog and relay-binlog on two separate extended volumes.

this is my configuration file for my primary:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql     
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock     
tmp_table_size=2G   
max_heap_table_size=2G   
log_bin=/mnt/volume_nyc3_09/mysql-logs/master-bin-log   
relay_log=/mnt/volume_nyc3_10/mysql-logs/relay-bin-log/primary-relay-bin   
expire_logs_days = 21    
binlog_format=ROW     
log_replica_updates=ON    
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G    
innodb_doublewrite=off    
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

The problem here is the slaves here are not able to catch up with their respective masters. I tried using iostat and figured that, The disk utilization is 100% for the binlog volume. The value of seconds behind master does not reduce at all. I have attached my slow slavestatus on primary and iostats. [image: iostat][image: slavestatus for primary]

Comment: what are you using as a PK out of curiosity?  We have replication lag issues but we're using UUIDs as pk instead of auto-incrementing INT.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `server_id` on each?

Comment: We are using 64GB of RAM for the server and server_ids are different in each cases.

Comment: Can you please answer the question about your primary key? When using ROW based binary logs, it's important to use a primary key, otherwise every update will do a table-scan. This is detrimental to replication performance, and it gets worse the larger the table is.

Comment: I also notice your configuration has disabled some durability options for InnoDB, which can help performance if you have a high write traffic. You should check the same options on your droplet instance. The durability might still be enabled, so there is enough overhead per write that it can't keep up with the rate of traffic.

Comment: Yes, we do use auto incrementing INT primary keys and innoDB options are same on both the instances.